# Сборщик мусора C#

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

Можно ли как-нибудь отследить работу сборщика мусора в Visual Studio 2022 (Т.е вообще всю работу, что он высвобождает, в каком порядке он это делает, и т.д)

Comment: [Garbage collection and performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/performance)

Comment: Практика показывает, что лучше писать чистый код и следить за аллокациями. Каждый раз, когда вы делаете `new` объект, выделяется память. Хотя, в соседнем вопросе вроде-как ваша проблема уже решена. :) Профилирование сборщика и памяти полезно на больших проектах, где перечитывать весь код не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вроде в `dotTrace` есть такое [Analyze Profiling Results/Filters/Events
Garbage Collection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/CLR_Activity.html).